# Differential equation, ball in free fall

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am wondering how to solve this differential equation:

A ball is falling straight down in free fall, its accelration(G) is set to 9m/s$^2$
it is affected by air resistance R = 0.25m(v(t))$^2$kg/ms$^2$

Now I have the equation:

$v^{\prime}(t) = \frac{1}{m}(G-R) = 9 - \frac{1}{4}(v(t))^2 $

I am to set starting point $v(0) = 0$. I am looking at how to solve the equation and find $v(t)$ Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but I am really bad at solving them. And unsure on how to procede.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with $\frac{dv}{dt}=9-\frac{1}{4}v^2$ and then separate variables, you get

$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{9-\frac{1}{4}v^2}dv=\int dt,\;\;\;$ so
$\displaystyle\int\frac{4}{36-v^2} dv=t+C$.

Using partial fractions, this gives

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\int\big(\frac{1}{6+v}+\frac{1}{6-v}\big)dv=t+C\;\;\;$ so $\displaystyle\ln\left(\frac{6+v}{6-v}\right)=3t+D$.

Now solve for $v$, using that $v=0$ when $t=0$.